# R equivalent of SELECT DISTINCT on two or more fields/variables

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe df with two or more columns, is there an easy way to use `unique()` or other R function to create a subset of unique combinations of two or more columns?

I know I can use `sqldf()` and write an easy `"SELECT DISTINCT var1, var2, ... varN"` query, but I am looking for an R way of doing this.

It occurred to me to try *ftable* coerced to a *dataframe* and use the field names, but I also get the cross tabulations of combinations that don't exist in the dataset:

```
uniques <- as.data.frame(ftable(df$var1, df$var2))
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`unique` works on `data.frame` so `unique(df[c("var1","var2")])` should be what you want.

Another option is `distinct` from [`dplyr` package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr):

```r
df %>% distinct(var1, var2) # or distinct(df, var1, var2)
```

**Note:**

For older versions of dplyr ([< 0.5.0, 2016-06-24](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/news.html#dplyr-0.5.0)) `distinct` required additional step

```r
df %>% select(var1, var2) %>% distinct
```

(or oldish way `distinct(select(df, var1, var2))`).

Answer (score 28):

@Marek's answer is obviously correct, but may be outdated. The current `dplyr`version (0.7.4) allows for an even simpler code:

Simply use:

```
df %>% distinct(var1, var2)
```

If you want to keep all columns, add

```
df %>% distinct(var1, var2, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

To KEEP all other variables in df use this:

```
unique_rows <- !duplicated(df[c("var1","var2")])

unique.df <- df[unique_rows,]
```

Another less recommended method is using row.names() #(see David's comment below):

```
unique_rows <- row.names(unique(df[c("var1","var2")]))

unique.df <- df[unique_rows,]
```

Comment: No. Operating over row names is always a bad idea. Just use `duplicated` if you want a boolean vector.

Comment: Because you've edited your answer without adding any note/contribution. So no one knew you actually fixed your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answers above, the data.table version:

```
setDT(df)

unique_dt = unique(df, by = c('var1', 'var2'))
```