# How to get rid of duplicated values in dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

My question is very similar to this one [Subset with unique cases, based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369961/subset-with-unique-cases-based-on-multiple-columns). The only difference is I don't want the duplicated value to show up in the final data frame.
Original dataframe:

```
df
v1  v2  v3   v4  v5
1  7   1   A  100  98 
2  7   2   A   98  97
3  8   1   C   NA  80
4  8   1   C   78  75
5  8   1   C   50  62
6  9   3   C   75  75
```

using `> df[!duplicated(df[1:3]),]` gets me

```
  v1 v2 v3  v4 v5
1  7  1  A 100 98
2  7  2  A  98 97
3  8  1  C  NA 80
6  9  3  C  75 75
```

But what I would like is

```
  v1 v2 v3  v4 v5
1  7  1  A 100 98
2  7  2  A  98 97

6  9  3  C  75 75
```

I tried using unique but it seems it's just keeping the column I am analyzing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We need to also get the `duplicated` from the other end

```
df[!(duplicated(df[1:3])|duplicated(df[1:3], fromLast = TRUE)),]
```